# React Redux - Trouble trying to use React-DnD and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-dnd

I was wondering why couldn't I get some of my components to work using ReactDnD and mapDispatchToProps.

I'm trying to drag and drop Services to Clients but I can't find my dispatch functions in props at my serviceSpec on the endDrag method.

Considering my mapDispatchToProps on my Service component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  dragService: (service) => { dispatch(dragService(service)) },
  dropService: (service, clientTarget) => { dispatch(dropService(service, clientTarget)) }
});
```

High-order functions to bond together DragSource + Service + State + Dispatch:

```
var reduxConnectedService = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Service);
export default DragSource('service', serviceSpec, collect)(reduxConnectedService);
```

render() method:

```
render (){
    const { isDragging, connectDragSource, service } = this.props;
    return connectDragSource(
      <a className="panel-block is-active">
        <CategoryIcon category={service.category}/>
        {service.name} | ${service.price}
      </a>
    )
  }
```

The spec object used to implement the dragSource specification (**here is the problem**):

```
const serviceSpec = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    return props.service;
  },
  endDrag(props, monitor, component){
    console.log(props);
  }
}
```

The console.log at endDrag function just show my Service Object because is being returned on the beginDrag function:

```
{service: {…}}
```

But my plan was to dispatch the action dropService here on endDrag, but I couldn't. The documentation says that (http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drag-source):

> beginDrag(props, monitor, component): Required. When the dragging
>   starts, beginDrag is called. You must return a plain JavaScript object
>   describing the data being dragged. What you return is the only
>   information available to the drop targets about the drag source so
>   it's important to pick the minimal data they need to know. You may be
>   tempted to put a reference to the component into it, but you should
>   try very hard to avoid doing this because it couples the drag sources
>   and drop targets. It's a good idea to return something like { id:
>   props.id } from this method.

I don't believe that I should return the dropService(dispatch) function on the beginDrag definition. So after hours trying to make it work, I started to pass the dropService function as a prop directly through the parent component (ServiceList):

```
{this.props.filteredServices.map((service, index) => (
     <Service service={service} key={service.name} dropService={this.props.dropService}/>
))}
```

Making this way I could dispatch the dropService action on the endDrag method like I wanted, the console.log can proves that:

```
{service: {…}, dropService: ƒ}
```

I could make it work but I can't understand why I couldn't get this to work using mapDispatchToProps. Is there any limitation while using React-DnD or am I making something wrong?

Any help will be appreciated, I cannot die with this doubt. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with these two lines:

```js
var reduxConnectedService = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Service);
export default DragSource('service', serviceSpec, collect)(reduxConnectedService);
```

Note the order: you wrap `Service` into a Redux container. Then you wrap the Redux Container with the `DragSource` container. Thus, in the component tree, the drag container is the *parent* of the Redux container, which means it doesn't receive the Redux props from it.

To fix that, make the drag container the *child* of the Redux container. You can do so by simply swapping the `DragSource()` and `connect()` calls:

```js
var dragService = DragSource('service', serviceSpec, collect)(Service);
var reduxConnectedService = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(dragService);
```

Comment: Thank you @DenisWashington, spot on! Good explanation too, it makes a lot of sense to have the DragSource as a child of Redux Container when thinking about props being passed.

Comment: Thank you @DenisWashington, you just saved my day.